# Launching SSRS Reports causes browser keep spinning

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, ssrs-2019

I try to launch the SSRS report and getting below error
"**Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier**' (using browser developer tools, Response TAB). No error information in network tab. The same is working ok in our lower environments. But issue is with production. I checked the SSRS logs at  : *D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\LogFiles*, it does not give any error.  Not sure the request is reaching the report server or not.

How we troubleshoot the issue ?  The ssrs version is 2019. Application is asp.net mvc. Is there any specific location in application server (iis) or report server (SSRS server), we can look further ?

This is the kind of url we are trying to generate :
*https://myserver.com/ReportServer_SQL?/Reports/StatsDetail&ClientID=123&Year=2023&rs:Command=Render&rs:ClearSession=true&rs:Format=EXCELOPENXML*

thanks

Comment: make sure the SSRS Report Server URL is accessible from the machine where you are trying to launch the report. check the user account trying to access the report has the necessary permissions on the SSRS server. try adding the custom user account to the iis app pool which has permission to access SSRS report. check console logs